# Linearly independent vectors generated from matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I came across this question recently:

Do there exist $n$ real $n\times n$ matrices $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$, such that for any
$n$-dimensional non-zero vector $v$, $A_1 v, A_2 v, \cdots, A_n v$ are always linearly independent?

It seems like a usual linear algebra question, but I can't think of any idea to approach it, and I can't come up with a counterexample either. Is there anything I've missed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: So for $n=2$, this is obvious as we can just take two rotation matrices with different angles. The resulting two vectors will always be on different lines. For $n>2$ however, rotation won't work as there'll be an axis of rotation, on which the vectors are eigenvectors, i.e., on the same line after rotation.

Comment: Given a none zero vector $v$ is there a matrix $A$ for which $v$ is a cyclic vector? That would answer the question if true, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: @Widawensen No matter what the axis of rotation is there will be a vector $w$ such that $w$ is an eigenvector. i.e. $Aw = w$, and so $w$ and $Aw$ will not be linearly independent.

Comment: For 3 dimensional rotation a selected vector can be on axis, then you can take two other rotations with different axes and it will be rotated.

Comment: @Enforce I suppose however that $w$ is not the vector from the list. The list starts from $A_1 w$., ends on $A_n w$, $...$ $n+1$ vectors would be always linearly dependent in n-dimensional space.

Comment: @Widawensen Yes I misread the question. Although this method still fails as explained in the comments to the answer below.

Comment: @Enforce. Yes, my method fails. I see it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(1)\iff(2)\iff(3)$ in the following:

1. $A_1v,A_2v,\ldots,A_nv$ are linearly independent whenever $v\ne0$.
2. $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iA_iv\ne0$ whenever $v\ne0$ and $(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)\in\mathbb R^n\setminus0$.
3. $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iA_i$ is invertible whenever $(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)\in\mathbb R^n\setminus0$.

So, you are essentially asking whether there exists an $n$-dimensional subspace of $n\times n$ real matrices in which all nonzero members are invertible. This is a non-trivial but solved problem: the answer is “yes” if and only if $n=1,2,4,8$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696769) for some references.

Comment: Really we can find such non-zero vector $v$ in 3-dimensional space that $R_x v, R_y v, R_z v$ are linearly dependent? ( operations here are rotations about perpendicular axes)

Comment: @Widawensen Let $v$ be the axis of rotation for $R_x^TR_y$. Then $R_xv-R_yv+0R_zv=0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation.